# how to get triangles to be right in the middle on top of each other, turtle

Tags: python, python-turtle

```
from turtle import *

NUMBER_OF_SHAPES = 4

for shape in range(1, NUMBER_OF_SHAPES + 1):

# Draw a Triangle
    for sides in range(3):
        forward(20 * shape)
        left(120)

# Move forward to start position of next triangle
    penup()
    left(120)
    forward(20 * shape)
    right(120)
    pendown()
```

Comment: Are you getting the wrong result?  You don't explain what's wrong with your code.

Comment: code is good, just want to get the triangles to be on top of each other, but also in the middle of each other

Comment: "The code is good but it doesn't give the results I want" is a contradiction.  (You should have given an example of what you were getting, and an example of what you were trying to get.)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`goto()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CSY1.png) to position the turtle where you want the triangle to start:

```
from turtle import *
import math

NUMBER_OF_SHAPES = 4
SIDE_LENGTH = 20

top = 0

for shape in range(NUMBER_OF_SHAPES):
    penup()
    goto(-shape * SIDE_LENGTH / 2, top)
    pendown()

    # Draw a Triangle
    for sides in range(3):
        forward(SIDE_LENGTH * (shape + 1))
        if sides == 1:
            top = pos()[1]   # Store where the apex is for next time
        left(120)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but i meant on top of each other,not inside. idividualy, starting from the smallest to the biggest .

Comment: @Dude Updated. If that's not right you will need to add a picture of what you want.

Comment: looks good now,thx